# Simulating the motion of a elastic body under gravity

Tags: simulation, numerical-analysis

I am doing a numerical simulation of a elasticity problem. It is very simple. A cuboid elastic body with the right end fixed on the wall, under the gravity(but here I set it to be 1 along the z-axis always), what is the motion of this elastic body? The initial displacement and velocity are 0 everywhere, that is, the static case. I use time step 100s, and the displacement converges, and I got the picture of the displacement of the elastic body when it converges. The mesh has 1482 tets with average edge length 4.00. I use a post-processing tool gmsh and got the picture:

[image]

I am not quite sure if this result is correct or not. Actually I am simulating an isotropic linear elastic body. Could anyone here give me some guidance about this, and if it is not correct, what the correct picture should looks like?

Thanks!

Re: Stefan M

I think my model is very clear, a cuboid isotropic linear elastic body with a fixed right end, and we want to know what is its motion when time evolves. I am using a new method, but anyone can use, for example, finite element method to simulate this and got the solution. Even the mesh are different, but the solution (if it converges) should be at least same in quality. That's why I am trying to ask this question.

Now I see I got something wrong, the solution I get now will not converge, this seems plausible.

Comment: You should be a bit more specific. What is the initial condition? What is your model? What algorithm do you use?

Comment: Hi, I think I have talked about my model, the isotropic linear elastic body, started from static condition. The algorithm is not important, I just want to check from the result if the algorithm is correct.

Comment: It is impossible to tell if your solution is correct. The details provided are only random bits from which it is impossible to replicate your problem. Moreover one cannot check a dynamic solution from a single snapshot, as much as it is impossible to validate a dynamic code just from a single example.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your model is well-posed, i.e. there is only one solution to the problem, and there is only the gravity as an external force. If it converges -- I assume this means that the solution doesn't change in time any more -- then it converges to the steady-state solution.

The steady state solution of what you describe is known to be [this, (last case with uniformly distributed load)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Bernoulli_beam_theory#Cantilever_beams).

Thus, your result is not correct.

Comment: Without damping the steady state solution will be a superposition of vibration modes, not a static one. The solution you point at is valid only for slender beams.

Comment: I agree. I was simply guessing what it might be.